# Calculating 4th power differences

Tags: equation, equation-solving, modelica

I am using Modelica for solving a system of equations for heat transfer problems, and one of them is radiation which is written as

```
Ta^4-Tb^4
```

Can someone say if it is computationally faster solving a system with the equation written as:

```
(Ta-Tb)(Ta+Tb)(Ta^2+Tb^2)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be a definitive answer to this question.  This is because the Modelica specification is used to formally define the problem statement but it says nothing about how tools solve such equations.  Furthermore, since most Modelica tools do symbolic manipulation anyway, it is hard to predict what steps they might take with such an equation.  For example, a tool may very well transform this into a Horner polynomial on its own (without your manual intervention).

If you are going to solve for the temperatures in such an equation as a non-linear system, be careful about negative temperature solutions.  You should investigate the "start" attribute to specify initial (positive) guesses when these temperatures are iteration variables in non-linear problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there are two reasons why splitting it into (Ta-Tb)(Ta+Tb)(Ta^2+Tb^2) is SLOWER and NOT FASTER.

1. (Ta^2+Tb^2) requires 2 multiplications and an addition, which means that (Ta-Tb)(Ta+Tb)(Ta^2+Tb^2) requires 4 multiplications and 3 additions. On the other hand, i guess that Ta^4-Tb^4 is done like this: ((Ta^2)^2 - (Tb^2)^2) which means 1 addition and 4 multiplications.
2. Mathematica, like a more generic compiler probably knows very well how to optimise these very simple expression. Which means that it is generally safer in terms of computation time to use simple patterns which will be easily caugth and translated into super efficient machine code.

I might obviously be wrong, but I cannot see any reason why (Ta-Tb)(Ta+Tb)(Ta^2+Tb^2) could be FASTER. Hope it helps.

Oscar

Comment: the model is solved with a DAE solver in Modelica, the variables Ta and Tb also depend on other (DAE) equations. It seems to me that the DAE solver sees `Ta^4-Tb^4` as a highly nonlinear fourth power equation whereas `(Ta-Tb)(Ta+Tb)(Ta^2+Tb^2)` is seen as less nonlinear, i.e. a linear model multiplied by a linear model multiplied by a second order nonlinear model resulting in a more stable iteration process.

Comment: So, this is not really computing as "calculating the value of" but rather "solving a system with the equation written as" which is quite different indeed.